# Reinitialise JScrollPane after AJAX post loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jscrollpane

Im'm loading posts in a div #reviewspostscont, the AJAX code works and the posts are loaded when the scrollbar gets to the end but I can't reinitialise JScrollPane to show them.
I tried different codes but nothing works, this is what i have so far.
Thanks in advance, Matt

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(function()
{
$('#reviewspostscont').each(
    function()
    {


        $(this).jScrollPane(
            {
                horizontalDragMaxWidth : 100
            }
        );
        var api = $(this).data('jsp');
        var throttleTimeout;
        $(window).bind(
            'resize',
            function()
            {
                if (!throttleTimeout) {
                    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                        function()
                        {
                            api.reinitialise();
                            throttleTimeout = null;
                        },
                        50
                    );
                }
            }
        );

        $(this).bind(
            'jsp-scroll-x',
            function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight)
            {
            var count = 2;
                if (isAtRight == true) {
        loadArticle(count);
        var api = $(this).data('jsp');
        api.reinitialise();
        count++;
    }


            }
        );

    }
  )




  });


  function loadArticle(pageNumber){    
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type:'POST',
                    data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop-reviews', 
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#reviewspostscont").append(html);   // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
                    }
                });

            return false;
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [autoReinitialise](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#autoReinitialise). [Here's a demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html) showing a similar example. [And another one](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html). [And another](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_height.html).

Comment: Thanks, I had already looked through the website, I can't the api.reinitialise... to work. Now i tried using 'autoReinitialise:true' under the line with 'horizontalDragMaxWidth : 100', but nothing changes and no errors in the console